# Stop collection view filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, observablecollection

I have two List boxes ,both has item source set as MyList.In listbox1 I want to filter the entries based on some predicate.I achieve that by following code

```
ICollectionView listview= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyList);

listview.filter(predicate)
```

My problem is I dont want this filtering to be applied to listbox2 but it is important for me to keep one itemsource.How can I achieve this.

```
  <ListBox Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
    <ListBox Name="listbox2" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
```

I tried setting VirtualizingStackpanel.IsVirtualizing to false ,but it doesnt work.

Comment: What you mean by `keep one itemsource`? What you want achieve by this way?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I have couple of views ,they show the same information but the graphical representation is different.So Data is same for these views but they differ in data templates.I do not want to create duplicate lists in my viewmodel and logic to keep them in sync thats the reason I want to keep same itemsource.

Comment: Perhaps use Refresh() if you want to add another filter.

Comment: @michael I think you misunderstood me ,I do not want filtering in one view to affect other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding the source collection to the list boxes, you can create a collection view source where you need filtering and bind its view to the list box.

```
public CollectionViewSource ViewSource1 { get; set; }


ViewSource1 = new CollectionViewSource { Source = MyList};
ViewSource1.View.Filter(predicate1)
```

Then bind the View of the view source to the first list box. You can bind the source collection to the second list box.

```
 <ListBox Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSource1.View}"/>
 <ListBox Name="listbox2" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
```

Comment: I am looking for a way if it can be done using same datasource.I have other list boxes also which use this ,I need to apply filtering only in one listbox.So just because of one listbox I do not want to create different view sources for all.

Comment: In such a case you can just create one view source, where you need filtering. For all other list boxes you can bind the source collection itself. <ListBox Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSource1.View}"/>  <ListBox Name="listbox2" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted.Please change the following <ListBox Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSource1}"/>
 <ListBox Name="listbox2" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSource2}"/>